# Untraceable errors in coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have a node application where the structure is as follows:

```
app.coffee -> routes -> controller -> service -> redis
```

Somewhere in my service layer, I had a bug like this:

```
if err?
    callback err
else if uid? 
    user = 
        uid: uid
        username: username
        callback null, user  # <- indentation is wrong
else
    callback null, null
```

See that callback call on line 7? It's indented one tab more than it should.
And here is what I receive when I run my app:

```
> coffee app.coffee
app.coffee:15:24: error: unexpected TERMINATOR
routes app 
                       ^
```

The mentioned lines on `app.coffee`, btw which don't match with the source file, are like this:

```
app.use app.router  

routes = require './conf/routes'
routes app
```

It took me quite a long time and a lot of will power to find the cause. Again, the bug is located 3 layer below the app, in service layer. But there is nothing on the error mentioning the whereabouts, only that there is an `unexpected TERMINATOR` on `app.coffee` file.

I'm quite new to coffeescript and node.js, so my question is how do you proceed, seasoned coffeescripters or noders, when you encounter such an error message and the cause is miles away? Maybe there are some best practices or methods for tracking such a bug? Or preventing it in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

To track errors like so, I would use a CoffeeScript to JavaScript converter to locate the error before there's an attempted execution. Since the stack trace will point to a compiled CoffeeScript file, only the file name is useful.

Tools like the one [here](http://js2coffee.org/) can be useful in that case, and you can post your script directly to see if it parses correctly. You could also use a [lint](http://www.coffeelint.org/) tool, such as this, for evaluation on code quality, as well as correct parsing errors.

Comment: I don't understand, why do I need to convert to Javascript? I'm  running it with CoffeeScript compiler in the first place, i.e. `coffee`? What is more annoying is, if I pass the buggy file to `coffee` it's able to detect the error in the correct place. So I guess `require` is messing things here. Thanks for coffeelint suggestion, I'll put it in grunt.

Comment: The CoffeeScript compiler, in the end, still compiles the script into JavaScript to run. That is where errors like yours occur, so converting a file manually will point out the location of the conversion error, instead of the runtime error.

Comment: Ok, but, this one is not a runtime error, it's a syntax error, i.e. a compile time error. So CoffeeScript compiler should catch this while compiling (while converting to Javascript), and in fact it does. If I try the compile the file with `-c` (compile), it throws me the error. The runtime part, I guess, is the part where the file is `require`d. But the question is, why then, it doesn't show the error on the correct file, instead of app.coffee?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your error pointed to, if it wasn't pointing to `app.coffee`, which file was it pointing to?

Comment: I meant, I know in which file the bug is, so if I do `coffee -c buggy_file.coffee` it shows me the error. This is of course obvious if you know where the error is. But the problem is, while running `coffee app.coffee` the buggy file is `require`d indirectly through layers, and the output is, as I put in the original question. There is no indication where the error is, and it shows as it is in `app.coffee`

Comment: The stack trace points to the compiled JavaScript instead of the CoffeeScript, which is why you'd be getting strange line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

hexacyanide suggested syntax checking using the `coffee` compiler. Which is awesome if you know where the error is (mentioned in the comments on that answer), but most of the time you don't have that hint.

What I do is compile all of my Coffeescript sources if I think there might be a syntax error. I describe how I do that in (last half of) [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17661805/224334).

Comment: Thanks. I've written my thoughts about this here: http://goo.gl/YXIQ4I It's basically same approach: Having an automated build/test system.